# postgresql - how to manipulate the query results?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have this query:

```
SELECT name::text, id::int, pass:bool FROM mytable;
```

which gives me this view table:

```
name   id    pass
------------------
A      123    t
B      234    t
C      345    f
```

How do I tell postgres to give me this instead

```
name   id    pass
--------------------
A      123   passed
B      234   passed
C      345   failed
```

I tried the `CASE WHEN condition THEN result;` but that just gives me another column 'case'.
(if there's no easy way for postgres, is there any in psycopg2 ? because I mainly use it to get the data I want)

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sort of formatting really belongs in your application (IMO), a simple dictionary should do the trick in Python or possible a dictionary combined with your localized string handling system if you care about people that don't read English.

Comment: @A.H oh haha actually no, I just wanted to show you guys the data types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT name::text, id::int, 
CASE WHEN pass = true THEN 'passed' ELSE 'failed' END AS pass 
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this one:

```
select case pass when true then 'passed' when false then 'failed' else null end pass from...
```